# Number of rows of a file is not known a priori

Tags: c, file, scanf

An exercise in C tell me to read infos from a file txt in which **the number of rows is not known a priori**. For example I have a file like this:

```
name surname tel
name1 surname2 tel2
```

I tought to use this function `fscanf()` in this way

```
FILE *fp

...

while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s\n", name, surname, tel) != EOF)
{
  //function
}
```

is it a right way?

Answer (score 0):

H2CO3 is right fscanf returns the number of fields matched.

The real problem is usually that you don't know how many rows are in the file and so you do not know how large a structure or array to allocate for the data.  One solution is to use a std:vector which can grow.

It is surprising how often code reads the file twice. Once to count the lines, allocate storage and then again to read the data.  That can be a sane solution.

Comment: @Jim You can't :) David, please fix your answer - this question is about C, not C++.